# "SQL Data type out of range" If NOT rs.EOF THEN

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript

I got a problem with `IF NOT rs.EOF THEN` statement in my script.
The error says "[ORACLE][ODBC] SQL data type out of range <-27>.

I want to execute the following query which works fine for a few years.
I think the error occured after updating the Oracle database to version 19c. But im not that sure about it.

```
qry_pkv = "SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 FROM NC301B " &_
          "WHERE (EDIPROC like 'P30_')" &_
          "AND (LF301M > 0) " & _
          "AND (MANDT = "& mdt &")" &_
          "AND (PATH301 LIKE '%\PKV_DAV\%') " &_
          "OR (PATH301 LIKE '%\pkv_dav\%') " &_
          "ORDER BY MANDT ASC; "

cn.Open connectionString                                                                                                ' Verbindung zum SQL Server wird hergestellt

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then                                                                                             ' Prüfung der Verbindung zum SQL Server.
        Call CheckError ("DB Verbindungsfehler")                                                                        ' Ergebnis wird an die Funktion CheckError übergeben.
    End If

    On Error Goto 0

    If cn.State <> adStateOpen Then                                                                                     ' Prüft ob Verbindung geöffnet ist. 
        WScript.Echo "Verbindung zur Datenbank kann nicht aufgebaut werden."                                            ' Ausgabe im Fehlerfall (Fenster)
        RC = 1                                                                                                          ' ReturnCode wird auf bei Verbindungsfehlern auf "1" gesetzt.
        Zeile = "Verbindung zur Datenbank kann nicht aufgebaut werden."                                                 ' Ergebnis wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
        Call Writelog (Zeile)                                                                                           ' Prozedur "WriteLog" wird aufgerufen   
        Call Ende                                                                                                       ' Prozedur "Ende" wird aufgerufen.
    End If

rs.open qry_pkv, cn, 3

        Zeile = "Skriptausfuehrung wird gestartet." 
        Call Trace (3,"I",Zeile)

If NOT rs.EOF THEN 

    rs.MoveFirst

        ReDim Preserve AusgabeDir_pkv(0)

            i=0
    
            Zeile = "PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse"                                                                             ' Überschrift für LOG-Datei.
            Call Trace (3,"@",Zeile)                                                                                    ' Überschrift wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.

            Do While Not rs.EOF                                                                                         ' Schleife für durchsuchen der Datenbank.
                ReDim Preserve AusgabeDir_pkv(i)
                ReDim Preserve MANDT_pkv(i)
                AusgabeDir_pkv(i) = rs("PATH301")                                                                       ' Ausgabeverzeichnis wird in Variable gespeichert und verarbeitet.
                MANDT_pkv(i) = rs("MANDT")
                Zeile = "Verzeichnis in Bearbeitung - " & "Mandant: " & MANDT_pkv(i) & " Pfad: " & AusgabeDir_pkv(i)    ' Status der Verarbeitung. 
                Call Writelog (Zeile)                                                                                   ' Status wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
                Call loeschen_pkv(AusgabeDir_pkv(i))                                                                    ' Funktion löschen wird aufgerufen um Verzeichnis zu leeren wenn älter n Tage.                                                                                          

                i=i+1
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop                        

    ELSE 

        Zeile = "PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse"                                                                                 ' Ergebnis wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
        Call Trace (3,"@",Zeile)                                                                                        ' Prozedur "WriteLog" wird aufgerufen           
        Zeile = "Keine PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse vorhanden."                                                                ' Ergebnis wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
        Call Trace (3,"-",Zeile)                                                                                        ' Prozedur "WriteLog" wird aufgerufen           
    
End If
    
cn.close
```

Comment: Do you need a wildcard at the end of the first like?

Comment: I think the SQL-statement works fine. If i type the command i get all informations that i need.

Comment: Test the `qry_pkv` variable with a `MsgBox()` function to see whether the outputted query string is what you expect, that’s basic VBScript debugging. It might be it’s expecting a string but you are passing it as if it is a numeric value, hence data type out of range.

Comment: Does the code actually error on `If NOT rs.EOF THEN`, or on the `rs.Open` line?  When it fails what's the value of `mdt` ?

Comment: The qry_pkv looks fine. The code fails on "IF NOT rs.EOF THEN" but i dont know why.

Comment: @rel0aded0ne Simple question, what is the data type of the field `MANDT`? If it’s a string it should have some qualifier to denote your looking for a string value instead of a numeric one, which is why I said output the query.

Comment: @user692942 the field MANDT is numeric. i declared "mdt" in my script as Const mdt = "000".

Call MsgBox (qry_pkv) looks like this: 

SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 FROM NC301B WHERE (EDIPROC like 'P30_') AND (LF301M > 0) AND (MANDT = 000) AND (PATH301 LIKE '%\PKV_DAV\%') OR (PATH301 LIKE '%\pkv_dav\%') ORDER BY MANDT ASC;

Comment: @rel0aded0ne what kind of numeric field takes `000` as a number? If you try that query in Oracle do you get the same error?

Comment: @user692942 000 is the number for a specific client in SAP. Each Customer has a different number. I dont get the error If i paste the select statement into Oracle. That works fine. I think It has something to do with that recordset.

Comment: @user692942 i figured it out. i dont know why but the problem was the command "rs.open qry_pkv, cn, 3" The ,3 seems to be the problem. Everything is working fine with the command "rs.open qry_pkv, cn". Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @rel0aded0ne the Oracle provider probably doesn’t like `adOpenStatic` as a [`CursorTypeEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15).